# Kendo dropdown - Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use a kendo dropdownlist and render the options using the Template method as shown http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/template.html (click ASP.NET MVC > template.cshtml). To simplify the problem I am simply trying to display the AccountDescription only.

Here is my code so far.

cshtml

```
    ...        
    <div class="editor-field">
        <script>
            function entityFiltering() {
                return {
                    entityId: $("#EntityId").val()
                };
            }
        </script>

        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountNumber)
           .Name("AccountNumber")
           .DataTextField("AccountShortCode")
           .DataValueField("AccountNumber")
            .Template("<table><tr><td width='100px'>${ data.AccountDescription } </td></tr></table>")
           .OptionLabel("Please select...")
           .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")
                                                         .Data("entityFiltering"))
                                     .ServerFiltering(true))
           .Enable(false)
           .AutoBind(false)
           .CascadeFrom("EntityId")
              )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SourceAccountNumber)
    </div>
    ...
```

The model looks like

```
public class Model {

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Short Code")]
    public string AccountShortCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Account Number")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string AccountDescription { get; set; }
}
```

When the dropdown list renders all the options are in the list but they display `undefined` If I select an option I can see the actual correct value binding on the grid so I think my problem is purely a display issue.

Comment: What does the JSON look like in your browser developer tools? Did you try taking the "data" prefix off the field in the template?

Comment: Share how that action looks like -> read.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")
And as Burke suggested share whats the actual response inside of the  network tab inside of Dev Tools/Firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to sort this after a few hours! I changed the syntax in the template to `#= data.AccountDescription #` and that's done the trick!

Comment: This was exactly my problem, and your solution fixed my problem as well, so thank you for posting!